Proof that ring of rational upper triangular matrices is a right Goldie ring
Let $R = T_n (\mathbb{Q})$ - ring of rational upper triangular matrices. I want proof that it's a right Goldie ring, i.e. it satisfies two conditions:

Any chain of right annihilators is stabilized: $\textbf{r}(S_1) \subseteq \textbf{r}(S_2) \subseteq \ldots \textbf{r}(S_n) = \textbf{r}(S_{n+1})$, where $\textbf{r}(S) = \{ r \in R\ \mid sr = 0, \forall s \in S \}$, $S \subset R$.
Uniform dimension $\mathrm{u.dim} R_R < \infty$, i.e. $R_R$ doesn't contain not contain infinite direct sums of non-zero right ideals.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove the first сondition.
For second condition we may use the following fact, that any ideal in $T_n (\mathbb{Q})$ has form $T_n (I)$, which $I$ - ideal in $\mathbb{Q}$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ has only two ideals: $\{0\}$ and inself. Therefore there cannot be infinite direct sums of non-zero right ideals.

Since it is a finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$ algebra, it is also right and left Artinian, and right and left Noetherian.
The fact that it's Noetherian makes both of the Goldie conditions hold immediately on both sides.
Really you could just say from the beginning that finite dimensionality makes it obviously Goldie.
